# Datatable refresh on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I've seen multiple posts for this type of question but after trying many,many things over a couple of days, I can't get this to work, probably as a result of my inexperience with javascript/UI.

Anyway, I have a background function that updates some database contents periodically but the user also has the ability to add and remove rows. So I wanted to add a refresh button to the table rather than the page but the refresh doesn't work. I tried adding the refreshData function inside the document.ready but, either the browser complained of where I put it or the `uitable` variable was undefined. I won't post everything else I've tried but I'll post what I have now which displays the table correctly but the refresh fails with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined
    at refreshData (fetch:1043)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (fetch:1)
Code:
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : href + "/refreshInstanceList",
            data : {"action":"get"},
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success : function(data) {
                instdata = data.success;
                var uitable = $('#userInventory').DataTable({
                    data : instdata,
                    columns : [ 
                        {
                            "data" : "hostname",
                            title : 'Hostname',
                            "render" : function(data, type, row, meta) {    
                                return data;
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "initComplete": function() {
                        $("#userInventory_filter").append('&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" onclick="refreshData()"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>');
                    },
                });
            },

            error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
                infoMessage = "\tAn error occurred whilst processing your request \n\tPlease contact Administrator to resolve this issue.";
                showInformationMessage(infoMessage);                    
            },
            complete : function() {}


        });
    });

    function refreshData() {
        var table = $('#userInventory').dataTable(); 
        table.ajax.reload();
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at this demo [codepen](https://codepen.io/surya-iitg/pen/QWbxMLq)

```
var table = $('#userInventory').dataTable();
table.ajax.reload();
```

Makes sense only when u supply 'ajax' property to datatable when creating it, so that it can reload.

look at this for [datatable ajax documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var uitable = $('#userInventory').DataTable({
    //data : instdata,
    ajax: {
      type : "POST",
      url : href + "/refreshInstanceList",
      data : {"action":"get"},
      async: false,
      cache: false,
    },
    columns : [
      {
        "data" : "hostname",
        title : 'Hostname',
        "render" : function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return data;
        }
      }
    ],
    "initComplete": function() {
      $("#userInventory_filter").append('&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" onclick="refreshData()"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>');
    },
  });

  $('#some_button').click(function refreshData() {
    var table = $('#userInventory').dataTable();
    table.ajax.reload();

    //Or
    //uitable.ajax.reload();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I had tried something similar but couldn't get the data to resolve so I wasn't sure what part was wrong. I had to use uitable.ajax.reload(); in the refreshData() function and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much - I wish I would have posted this earlier, could have saved a few days and grey hairs!